# Is there a way to set a localised global validation message in Orbeon Forms?

Tags: orbeon

I am using Orbeon 2016.1 to develop forms in English and Welsh. However, the only way I can see to translate the default validation message, "Missing or incorrect data" is to untick the default message and paste in the translated version.

There is some xpath in one of the Formula which is preventing me from saving any changes, which means I will need to add an `<alert/>` node for each control in the resources instance.

If there is a property to configure a default localised validation message? This would save lots of time going through a large form!

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you share the XPath which doesn't work?

Comment: I think the XPath does not work because we have modified each bound select1 node in the form model to have 3 sub-nodes.

Comment: Hi @ebruchez, sorry for the delay - here is an example of the XPath code which causes the form to crash...   `string-length() = 0 or (number() >= 0 and number() <= 110)`

Comment: It's basicially to validate that when the field is not empty, the number is within the limits for imperial weight units (stone).

Answer (score 1):

You can override built-in Form Runner resource using properties, and this for all your forms, or just certain forms. For more on this, see the section [Overriding resources](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-runner.html#overriding-resources) in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you @avernet.  Should we extract the Form Runner .jar resource file under the WEB-INF/resources folder?

Comment: @jtb I would recommend you just put there only the files you are planning to modify. In the future this will make upgrading to a new version of Orbeon Forms much easier as, this way, you will know what files potentially need to be merged.